# Number pattern matching for a range in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, range

I want to select columns in Oracle: Code and Number based on the condition,

If number is any of the following return “E”: ###7890001 through ###7890999

where #(first 3 digits) could be any digit. These numbers are saved as string values so I need to cast them in appropriate data type too.

The data returned would look like this:

```
Code         Number
E            2347890001
E            9567890456
E            5647890999
```

Thanks in adavnce!!

Comment: If all you need is to return code `E` for those strings, you don't **need** to cast anything in a different data type. Why do you think you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your problem description is correct, your inputs are always 10-digit strings, and you must return code `E` if and only if the four digits in the middle are `7890`. Right? If so, the simplest solution is to use the LIKE condition. Note that `number` is a reserved keyword, so it can't be used as column name (I hope your column name is not really `number`, is it?)

The string in the `LIKE` condition is hard to read; it consists of three underscore characters, then 7890, then three more underscore characters. The underscore stands for exactly one character (**any** character).

```
with
  simulated_data (num) as (
    select '1234567890' from dual union all
    select '3337890456' from dual union all
    select '7897890455' from dual union all
    select '9998887774' from dual
  )
select num, case when num like '___7890___' then 'E' end as code
from   simulated_data
order  by num
;

NUM        CODE
---------- ----
1234567890  
3337890456 E
7897890455 E
9998887774
```

Comment: my 'num' column is varchar so need to convert it to number to match numbers from ###7890001 to ###7890999 basically a range.

Comment: @user12816412 - Repeating what you already said is not helpful. I asked you **why** you think you need to convert to number. I already showed you, in my Answer, that you don't **need** to convert to number to solve your task. If you need to convert to number, it must be for some other reason. Or, perhaps, you need to use it for other ranges, not the one you put in your question... in which case, you should post a better example.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
where code = 'E' and
      substr(number, -7) between  '7890001' and '7890999'
```

EDIT:

```
select (case when substr(number, -7) between  '7890001' and '7890999' then 'E' end) as code
```

Comment: E is returned if the pattern is matched the numbers come from a column called 'Number'

Comment: @user12816412 . . . In that case, just put the logic in a `case` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_number` with `mod` and `on conversion error` (oracle 12.2 or higher) as following:

```
Select 'E' as code, 
        number
   From your_table
  Where MOD(TO_NUMBER(number DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR), 10000000) 
        between  7890001 and 7890999;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Please share the actual query that you are executing. Here issue may be the name of the column which is number